# Moving Android Studio Project between computers

Tags: android

At work, I program with Android Studio IDE, when I finish my working hours I want to continue working with the project at home, so I use WinRAR to compress all Android Studio Project Folder, then I upload the compressed folder to Google Drive and at home, I download the folder decompressed it and when I open the project, the same error appears.

Why is so complicated to move Android Studio Projects through devices, and if you know a better way to move the projects, please suggest that way.

Comment: I would suggest using version control instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to manage projects is using some sort of **Version Control System** and having a repository on cloud and you can easily sync your progress from home or work.

**Git** is one such system and **github** one such cloud repository management place.

**EDIT:** This is a basic representation of any Version Control System Coupled with Cloud Repository. Hope it helps you to understand better.
[image]

Comment: @DavidSuescunPelegay Have a look at Basic diagram to  get better grasp of this concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use Github for keeping track of all my project versions.

Comment: you can also look at an alternative - i.e. **bitbucket** main difference between two is that bit bucket lets you keep private repository for **Free**. Whereas github requires you to pay for it. Although openSource collaboration is better on Github. If you are the only one working then also look at bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing it wrong.  Use version control (svn, git, mercurial, cvs, whatever you want), and just redownload it to your new PC.  Zipping files between computers was considered archaic in the 90s.